# Errors after installing Chrome Dev along with Stable

Tags: google-chrome, ppa

I recently installed chrome dev version, even when I had chrome (stable) already installed.

After checking for updates with `sudo apt update` I get the following errors (maybe they are warnings).

[image]

How do I deal with them? And what is the cause.

Extra Info:
I installed dev by downloading the `.deb` package, and the executing `sudo apt install /home/abhay/Downloads/google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb`.

Also I can see two chrome PPAs in `Software & Updates`.
[image]

Is that somehow related to this incident? Is that a problem, having two same PPAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be removed by simply deleting the files using `rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-unstable.list*` command.

Each time you install an app, a link is created to its repository (or PPA), which are stored here. But when you uninstall a package, it doesn't clear itself from this location. Since chrome and chrome-unstable are from similar locations, hence the error (since both are contradictory). And hence you need to remove these files for chrome-unstable from this location.

These files are also visible in the `Software & Updates`, hence removing the file from here remove it from `Software & Updates` also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It clearly says that chrome source list have been configured multiple times. Just uncheck one of them.

Also, you could install unstable version just by:

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-unstable
```